# Looking for a good material to adopt unit-test coding approach

Tags: unit-testing

this is something I know I should embrass in my coding projects but, due to lack of knowledge and my legendary lazyness, I do not do.

In fact, when I do them, I feel like overloaded and I finally give up.

What I am looking for is a good book/tutorial on how to really write good tests -i.e useful and covering a large spectrum of the code -.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Excellent book that covers unit tests for **legacy code** in particular is Michael Feather's "**Working Effectively with Legacy Code**"

[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at 'katas' - in particular testing katas. Without knowing what language you use, it's hard to give a more concrete answer.

http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/11/21/whats-all-this-nonsense-about-katas

Comment: I am mainly developing in:

- erlang
- *lisp
- python
- java
- SQL

But I need a general approach to the unit-testing science.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Roy Osherove's The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.artofunittesting.com/), especially if you're working in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know what language or platform you mean? In regards to .Net [Test-Driven Development in Microsoft® .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6778&locale=en-us). Provides you TDD principles and practices with examples. Have a copy at home and the office. Used it as a primer before getting into TDD and NUnit myself .

Answer (score 1):

This guy knows what he's talking about: http://orthocoders.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a good book going over how to Unit Test I would recommend Kent Beck's : [Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530).  He is the person who really started the idea of Unit Testing, so regardless of language this would be a great book to read to get a good foundation.

Also, Don't let the title discourage you.  It does talk about TDD, but it's really just a good easy overview, of how to write effective unit tests, and how they should affect your design which is a key component of writing unit tests.